# Spring LDAP: fail-safe LDAP searches

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm using Spring to make some queries to a LDAP server. However, a `CommunicationException` is thrown by `LdapTemplate.search()`  and crashes my application when the connection with the LDAP server becomes unavailable.

Where should I handle this? I see a `NamingException` in [`LdapTemplate.search()` method documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html), but I'm not sure if I should handle this exception or `CommunicationException`.